# What image does our new theme need for the error page?

Tags: discussion, theme

What image does our new theme need for the error page?

Simple enough question. We need ideas people.

special page listings: [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Cooking: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/error

English: https://english.stackexchange.com/error

Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/error

Super User: https://superuser.com/error

Comment: DBA:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/error

Answer (score 7):

How about this tribute I made to the ["All your base"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) meme?

[image: ALL YOUR DATABASE ARE BELONG TO US]

Doing a quick Google search, it looks like [others](http://hornhouse.net/ayb.htm) have already thought of this.  However, I think my version is cleaner.  :)

Comment: This one is great. I'm going to use it in our next deployment

Comment: @Jin - Sweet! I just uploaded a cleaner version of the image to fix the text alignment.

Comment: Got an error page on dba.se earlier today... I have to admit, seeing this pop up made me smile.

Answer (score 2):

A face-palmed over-worked harrassed DBA-looking chap or chapette?

Edit: Nick's is better

Answer (score 1):

How about the site logo with flames shooting out the top.

A Cartesian product might work.

The problem is that most ideas would be language specific. For Oracle an ORA-600 error would work, but I think the site needs something more generic.